# What does the extra arguments to call instruction used for?

Tags: assembly

I'm using WinDBG to analyze a core dump and notice this `call` instruction:

`call    dword ptr [AcroRd32+0xe52cc (012252cc)] ds:0023:012252cc={kernel32!HeapCreate (760fef74)}`

I understand the `call dword ptr [XXXX]` part but what's the `ds:` part used for?

Or any better reading on this kind of syntax? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is simply WinDBG telling you what the dword argument currently corresponds to.

To clarify, the actual instruction is

```
call dword ptr [012252cc]
```

What follows is WinDBG information that the 0x012252cc address corresponds to `kernel32.HeapCreate`.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the manual to interpret these extra information?

Comment: WinDBG probably gets this information from the module's Import Address Table. See the Microsoft Portable Executable specification (sorry, I don't have a link handy - it's available on msdn) for more information if you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check intel manual for system programming
Ds (data selector) it is a cpu register containing number in the GDT (20) for segment translation and privileges level (3 - ring 3) for data accessing.